# How does this snippet of zsh code keep track of time? Doesn't seem to have date or anything

Tags: zsh

I came across this snippet of code in the prezto repo, and im really stumped.

It appears to rebuild zsh comp every 20 hours, but I can't figure out how.

`(Nm-20)` seems to be calling into a subshell, but `Nm-20` itself is not a program.

`($BLAH/zcompdump)` should be a file, but it shouldn't be executable, so why is it surrounded by `()`?

Lastly, `if (( $#_comp_files ))` seems to be that the outer`()` is a test to see if `( $#_comp_files )` is true or not, but what is `$#_comp_files`?

```sh
# Load and initialize the completion system ignoring insecure directories with a
# cache time of 20 hours, so it should almost always regenerate the first time a
# shell is opened each day.
autoload -Uz compinit
_comp_files=(${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump(Nm-20))
if (( $#_comp_files )); then
  compinit -i -C
else
  compinit -i
fi
unset _comp_files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is the use of Glob Qualifiers.
At the end of a filename, you can add parenthesis with filters.

`.zcompdump(Nm-20))` will select this file only if modified less than 20 days ago.
The N says to not display an error (NULL_GLOB).

It's missing a `h` to have `Nmh-20` to get it if modified less than 20 h ago.

`man zshexpn` then search for Glob Qualifiers.

Try it yourself with

```
cd /tmp
touch myfile
z=(myfile(Nmm-1)) ; echo $z
```

wait a minute and try again the last line, with or without N